# Frase encabezada por “como” – función sintáctica

Tags: sintaxis

> Pocas veces salía a ver un enfermo en un día de guardar, **como no fuera
>   de extrema urgencia**.

¿Me podríais ayudar a identificar la función sintáctica de la frase en negrita por favor? Diría que es una frase condicional (en caso de que se pueda sustituir la parte "como no fuera" por "a no ser que"). ¿O me estoy equivocando?

Comment: @aparente001: what's wrong with the term "oración"?

Comment: "oración" es correcto."frase" también lo es. Puedes rechazar la edición si así te parece.

Comment: The edit can be rolled back.  Apparently I was mistaken.  I thought *oración* was for a full sentence.

Comment: @aparente001 note I rejected your [suggested edit](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/12900), since _prohíben_ does have an accent. Check in [DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UK8SJRJ) for its conjugation! Otherwise it would sound /proi-ben/ instead of /pro-hi-ben/.

Comment: @fedorqui - Oh, good to know.  I think that was a different question but I suppose you couldn't ping me there.  I guess the accent is needed because the H doesn't really count.

Comment: "oración" usually requires a verb, but some people consider some sentences to be "oraciones" even if the verb is implicit.

Comment: @aparente001 indeed, there is no way to ping from a suggested edit, so I had to do it here. The key here is not the H, but the fact that _oi_ is a diphthong, so you need the accent to break it.

Comment: @fedorqui- Thanks for the explanations.  I knew about *oi* (e.g. *yo oí* -- well, maybe that's not the best example) but I was imagining the H would solve the problem, and I apparently googled sloppily.  I'm learning a lot from this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estás en lo correcto. Es una forma en desuso de usar "como", pero aparece bastante en literatura.

Creo que corresponde a la acepción 15 que [aparece en la rae](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9xWAAKF%7C9xWxEd9):

> 15. conj. desus. Sustituía a que para introducir una subordinada. Sabrás como hemos llegado sin novedad. U. actualmente solo con ciertos
>       verbos. Sal con ellos y verás como lo pasas muy bien.

Reemplazando "como" por "que" queda:

> Pocas veces salía a ver un enfermo en un día de guardar, que no fuera
>   de extrema urgencia.

Comment: Me parece acertada tu respuesta, pero no creo que la coma funcione bien delante de "que", como sí funciona delante de "como".